# A question about the first mdat box of the fmp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, fmp4

The header of the first mdat box of the fmp4 file has a section of file description information data, is this section of information necessary? If not, will it affect the decoding of the fmp4 file?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is informational metadata written into an SEI by x264. It is not related to mp4 in any way. No it is not required.